# Microsoft Surface (Windows 8) App to sync data with a DB behind a VPN server?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, vpn

I am still learning about microsoft surface (windows 8 or Windows RT) programming, however I am having an issue that I would need ideas about how to get it done.
The app is supposed to sync data with a db behind a vpn tunnel. I don't know exactly how the syncing will be implemented in this case. 
How would this communication be implemented? what are the options to implement this thing? (xml request, vpn client, email client,..etc) any ideas or references will be very helpful.

Comment: I've had to work with this and its rough, does the phone have to be on the vpn or do you just need the call to go through?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by the "call to go through". There is no specific requirement about this. I am looking into all possible options.

Comment: Is your question about Windows Mobile, or Windows Phone? Clearly different

Comment: Thanks Nicolar for bringing the attention to such difference. its actually about Windows Surface. (I'll update the question). how would you do it for windows 8 surface?

Comment: There is no "Windows Surface". You need to tell us specifically what operating system. Windows Mobile, Windows Phone 7, Windows Phone 8, Windows RT, or Windows 8? Once you have determined which of those you're developing for, please update your title, question, and tags.

Comment: Thanks mason, question is updated. "Most likely" it will be a Windows 8.1 but I would also like to know if it will will be a different way if its Windows RT.